# Is there a better way to sort an ObservableCollection and display it sorted in a Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, observablecollection

Currently I have a listview that displays files. As files are added, I want them sorted by name. It is also VERY IMPORTANT that the collection itself is sorted as there are operations that need to cycle through the this collection in name order. Essentially rhe files are later uploaded to an FTP site and then are highlighted green in the listview. To ensure it works from the "top" down, I need to make sure the collection is also in the same order as it is displayed.

What I have have currently WORKS, but I am not sure if this is the best and most efficient want to do it. I am also trying to somewhat adhere to MVVM.

In the XAML, I have a section of code to sort a collection. In the ViewModel, I add items to the collection and once that is done, I sort the collection. It seems to work but I am worried it is not as efficient as it could be.

**XAML:**

```
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedListViewSource" Source="{Binding Selected_Photos_Binding}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

    <ListView x:Name="selected_files" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedListViewSource}}"
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    public ObservableCollection<FileData> _Selected_Photos_Binding = new ObservableCollection<FileData>();
    public ObservableCollection<FileData> Selected_Photos_Binding
    {
        get
        {
            return _Selected_Photos_Binding;
        }
        set
        {
            _Selected_Photos_Binding = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected_Photos_Binding"));
        }
    }
```

---

This section is where I take a list of files from a buffer collection and then populate the observable collection.

```
            foreach (string entry in Selected_List_Buffer)
            {
                Selected_Photos_Binding.Add(new FileData()
                {
                    Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(entry),
                    Path = entry
                });
            }

            Selected_Photos_Binding = new ObservableCollection<FileData>(Selected_Photos_Binding.OrderBy(n => n.Name));
```

Comment: It looks like the CollectionViewSource is sorting, no need to sort in the viewmodel too. Am I missing something?

Comment: By efficient, do you mean performant?

Comment: Where is the 3rd snippet? Which class/method?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I added a reason why in my post.

Comment: @RoberHarvey I guess that is also what I am looking for. Performance is somewhat important.

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle What do you mean? What I have posted is what does the work.

Comment: Thanks. If it's critical for the collection to be in the same order as displayed, sort it in the viewmodel and don't use a CollectionViewSource, just bind `ItemsSource="{Binding Selected_Photos_Binding}"`. If the viewmodel cares about the order of the collection, then it's appropriate for the viewmodel to take responsibility for ordering it. Sorting in that case is something the view should not interfere with.

Comment: @EdPlunkett wow...it was not doing that before. I might have changed something else and also for some reason I did not think that changing of the order would trigger an update for the view.

Comment: The improvement can be done and it has nothing to do with wpf.  Because  Selected_Photos_Binding is already sorted, there's no need to re-sort each time a file is added.  When you add the file, figure out where it should go. The performance by doing so is linear i.e. O(n)

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle Well, I am only sorting after a group of files are added. The user has a browse window and selects files to be added. Once added, it firsts adds all the files to the collection and then runs a single sort on the collection.

Comment: The point is when you add each file to the collection, add it to the proper position, then you won't have to run the sort again (even if it's a single sort). In other words, why add it to the collection and run the single sort again? Why NOT add it the correct position in the collection?

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle So you are saying adding 100 files and running logic on each one to determine where it goes is more efficient than adding them and then sorting later?

Comment: I see your code now. If you add 100 files to the collection, and then run sort, performance is O(nlogn), which is better than I proposed which would incur O(n*n)

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle So...you made assumptions without looking at the code...not very efficient now huh? :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160150/discussion-between-kevin-le-khnle-and-david-bentley).